# Hi , I am trying to create a pdf from webpage url. once the pdf downloaded. i coundn't open the pdf

Tags: java

when i am trying to open the downloaded pdf , it says We can't open this file ....Something went wrong.

Here is my code.....

```
String path = envString
    +"MetalSpecActionServlet?source=search_eu.jsp&action=open_na2066&specno="
    +na2066BO.getSpecNo()+"&specType=NA2066" ;

try {                                               
      URL url = new URL(path); 
      
      // Open a connection to the URL 
      URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 
       
      // Get the input stream from the connection 
      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); 
      
      // Create a FileOutputStream to write to the file in my local path
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pathNameEN); 
      
      // Read from the input stream and write to the file 
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
      int bytesRead; 
      
      while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
            } // Close streams 
            inputStream.close(); 
            outputStream.close(); 

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FileInputStream fisEN = null;

// upload to database
File fileEN = new File(pathNameEN);

try {
    fisEN = new FileInputStream(fileEN);
    fileHandlingRepository.fileUpload(na2066BO.getSpecNo(), fisEN, "PDF_EN", ".pdf");                           

} catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
    if (eutype.indexOf("2066") != -1) {
        throw new MetalSpecBusinessException(MetalSpecMessageConstants.MS_EU2066_INTERNAL_ERORR,
                new String[] { "upload PDF(s)" });
    } 
    }
 finally {
    try {
        if (fisEN != null) {
            fisEN.close();
        }                       
    } catch (IOException exc) {
    }
}
```

Is anyone knows ,How to resolved this ?

Comment: You should inspect what is inside the file. It looks like you downloaded a webpage that is some kind of HTML or XML and uploaded it somewhere that expects a pdf.  Those are different formats and you did not actually do a conversion from one to the other as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please have a look at how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Which file is unreadable: The one saved to `pathNameEN` or the one uploaded to `fileHandlingRepository`?

Comment: pathNameEN is my local path and fileHandlingRepository is having the code of inserting the pdf into database.

Comment: I figured that much. Now, do you want to answer my question or not?